# Is there a way to store spawn object (child_process) in database and reuse it?

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

Why I need this?

1. Client make request to server
2. Server receive request, starts python script with spawn (child_process)
3. If python script needs more information to proceed running, I must send user email with link which leads to page with only one input field
4. When user fill that, I must continue SAME process (running script) and enter that in command line with ls = spawn('command', args) and then ls.stdin.write()

How I can do this? My idea is, to get object from

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const ls = spawn('command', [args]);
insertInDb(JSON.stringify(ls));
```

And then use it with

```
const ls = JSON.parse(databaseInput);

ls.stdin.write(input);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

No, but I can't imagine a scenario in which you would want to. What if your user emails back tomorrow? Or next week? Or never? You just have these dangling python processes clogging up your system.

If you're positive you'll get quick feedback you can talk your python script via a shared file descriptor:

```
const cp = spawn(cmd,args,{
  stdio:['pipe','pipe','pipe','pipe']
});
cp.stdio[3].on('data',(data)=>{
  // data from python's fd 3
});
cp.stdio[3].write('foobar'); // write to python's fd 3
```

But you almost certainly should just have two different python scripts.

Comment: It's third party script, that done some scraping and it needs sometimes additional informations that user must enter. It should not last greater than 5 minutes

Comment: It's not a good solution. You should validate the necessary information is present before running or split it. Even though it's third party it's still a script you can easily alter.

What about this:
Find your split spot and write the vars out in JSON. Store it in your server, fix vars if necessary, run the second half with the vars as env variables or argv values.

Comment: So it's impossible to store like string object of spawn?

Comment: Well, very little is impossible with some creativity and a solid understanding of what you're after, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Or can I send stdin on existing pid? Storing only the pid

Comment: No. You could talk via named pipe.